# gitlab: Any REST API to retrieve languages used in a repo

Tags: gitlab-api

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/analytics/repository_analytics.html#repository-analytics-for-projects

Is there a REST API in gitlab to retrieve the analytics for the languages used in a repository?

I want to do the same for at a complete org level if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usage is straight forward :

`curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <__ACCESS_TOKEN__>" https://gitlab.mydomain.com/api/v4/projects/<ID>/languages`

docs : [Gitlab docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html#languages)